# перевести из 7 php на 5

Tags: php

есть запись в массиве (7 php)

```
'start' => ((($route['page'] ?? 1 ) - 1) * $max),
```

в 5.6 php оно ругается на синтаксис **??**, как эту строчку в 5 php оформить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`??` это оператор объединения с `NULL`. В данном случае его можно попробовать раскрыть например вот так:

```
$page = 1;
if(isset($route['page']))
{
    $page = $route['page'];
}
. . .
'start' => (($page - 1) * $max),
```